# Facebook: is it possible to get insights of impressions for a specific OpenGraph object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

my app is generating OpenGraph objects for users and I want to give those users analytics for their objects (total impressions, clicks, etc..).

I tried using the graph API to get those insights with https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/insights but I don't see how I can filter the results by a specific OpenGraph object.

is it possible to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You can pull, for example, insights data for individual posts as follows:

First, get the list of posts for a page:

```
/<pageId>/posts
```

Then for each post get the insights which will look something like this:

```
/<pageId>_<postId>/insights
```

Note: It's best to batch call the post insights into one request.